# Extbase addAdditionalHeaderData(...) in actioncontroller, include same CSS twice

Tags: css, typo3, extbase, typo3-4.5

For my extbase extension I need a CSS that I include in all actioncontrollers with:

```
$this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . t3lib_extMgm::siteRelPath($this->request->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/Public/css/mystyle.css" />');
```

If I now have a page where multible plugins of my extensions are included, I have multible CSS includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/css/mystyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3conf/ext/myext/Resources/Public/css/mystyle.css">
```

### Edit

I could also do the following:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData[100] = '<link ...>';
```

But as far as I know is that just the old way.

Comment: Why are you including the CSS in the controller? Can't you use TypoScript?

Comment: Optionally add some checkbox to you flexform (so you can add headers if it's checked) and make sure that's checked only for one instance of plugin per page

Comment: @lorenz: Different actions can include diffrent CSS (and JS), so just a `page.headerData.100.value = <link ...>` in the setup.txt will include the files also on sides I dont need them. Any other idea with typoscript?

Comment: @biesior that would be a option, but it's not a realy neat solution.

Comment: @nbar: if you really desire automatic adding (without checkbox) just check with simple SQL query if the page has inserted `tt_content` with the same type `tt_content` and `sorting` smaller  then current record.

Comment: Maybe you also should re-think your approach in times of CSS merging, LESS and co.

Comment: For now I will use the old way. @lorenz got any good link to CSS merging on runtime? I don't want to put all CSS files into 1 file. (And the same with JS files)

Comment: @nbar: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/ws_less/current/ is a Less compiler (on of the many Less extensions for TYPO3). Of course you can also just use CSS concatenation (but from TYPO3 4.6): http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/Setup/Config/Index.html#concatenatecss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After years I use `vhs:asset` now to add CSS/JS to extensions:

```
<v:asset.script path="EXT:my_extension/Resources/Public/js/javascript.js" name="collectionjs" standalone="1" />
<v:asset.style path="EXT:my_extension/Resources/Public/css/style.css" name="collectioncss" standalone="1" />
```

The `name` attribute is unique, So if you have another include with the same name, it will overwrite the old include.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to include CSS and JS with static TypoScript, as it easier adjustable, if someone would like to have its own CSS.
You should exclude it from the TYPO3 CSS-Merger if you include this TS only on the Extension page.

Just use the following TypoScript

```
page.includeCSS.myExtCss = EXT:myext/Resources/Public/css/mystyle.css
page.includeCSS.myExtCss.excludeFromConcatenation = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with using the old way:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData[$this->request->getControllerExtensionKey()."CSS1"] = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . t3lib_extMgm::siteRelPath($this->request->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/Public/css/mystyle.css" />';
```

For every CSS or JS i include I use another sufix: CSS2, CSS3, JS1, JS2 and so on.
So if another controller will include the same file it will just overwrite the old entry in the additionalHeaderData Array.

Comment: I solved it for now, but I will let the question open for a while to find a good way without using the old way.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a class variable to mark that you already included your stylesheet. The value of this variable should be alive the whole request.

In your controller class, define your class variable / static property:

```
public static $includedMyStyle;
```

in your controller action:

```
if (!self::$includedMyStyle) {
  $this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . t3lib_extMgm::siteRelPath($this->request->getControllerExtensionKey()) . 'Resources/Public/css/mystyle.css" />');
  self::$includedMyStyle = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Old question, but it's worth to mention...*

You need to change approach here. If you have several instances of the same plugin on the same page which should behave differently, you just need to use FlexForm for adding options for each instance, they should start with **`settings`** and each part separated by dot is next level of an associative array, for an example:

```
<settings.includeHeaderData>
    <TCEforms>
        <exclude>0</exclude>
        <label>Include header data...</label>
        <config>
            <type>check</type>
            <default>0</default>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.includeHeaderData>
```

so in your action you can use it like:

```
if (intval($this->settings['includeHeaderData']) > 0){
    $this->response->addAdditionalHeaderData('<link ...>');
}
```

or if node where:

```
<settings.foo.bar.baz.something>
    ...
</settings.foo.bar.baz.something>
```

you can access it in the controller like:

```
$mySetting = $this->settings['foo']['bar']['baz']['something'];
```

Comment: I use `vhs:asset` now to add js/css. Think it's the cleanest way to do it in combination with fluid. BUt thanks for the answer to such an old question :)

Comment: Interesting why downvote, I don't care about points rather I'd like to know what's the motivation ;)

Comment: Can't tell cause it was not my downvote. I upvoted to balance it out cause your answer is not wrong (But I dislike that the editor need manuel work to make this work)